# Pick the odd one out: 146, 821, 704, 603

Tags: mathematics, number-property, odd-one-out

I am preparing for an exam, and I came across this puzzle(aptitude) question.

The question is to Pick the 'odd one out' and there are four options given.

> 146, 821, 704, 603

The correct answer is 603. Can somebody explain why that is?

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to Puzzling :) Can you provide us with some extra context for this question, please? Was this in a test somewhere, or a newspaper - where did you find it? Was it one of a set of questions that shared a particular theme? And was the question presented just like this - text-only - or were there any images or special fonts involved? (This info might help us make some headway, as odd-one-out puzzles can often have multiple justifiable answers...) Thanks!

Comment: (My suspicion is that 603 is the odd-one-out because the digits of all the other numbers sum to 11, but this might be 'too simple' for certain puzzle set-ups, and if there is additional context then this usually helps get a firmer answer...)

Comment: @stiv Your comment makes sense. I think that is the logic behind the answer. Can you help me with one more,(Currently I can't post on the forum). Odd one out among 214, 350, 520, 738. The correct answer is 214.

Comment: @Max One question per question, please. You'll just have to wait out the timer - it's meant to keep new folks from flooding the site until they learn the ropes. Also, please tell us **what the source of these problems is**. We require [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259/69582).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be [603] as all the other's digits add up to 11.

1+4+6=11

8+2+1=11

7+0+4=11

**6+0+3=9**